# LINQ Search in collection of object containing object which contains list

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

please help in creating simple c# Linq query

```
List<A> X;

class A{
public string phone;
...some other props
}
class B{
public string xyz;
public List<B> bobj;
}
class C{
public string pqr;
public B;
}
..
```

Now I have list of C;

```
List<C> tobesearched;
```

How to get all C i.e. `List<C>` from `tobesearched` for a phone which contains "123"

Comment: Thanks, Sorry I couldn't post it properly

Comment: I believe `bobj` should be of type `List<A>`. But anyway, what did you try so far? Can you show your query and describe results you got with that query

Comment: Frankly, no clue.. cad.SelectMany(s => s.Customer.phonenumbers)
                                            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.phone == kp.Value))

Comment: your ```tobesearched``` list does not include any ```A``` not sure how would you like to search for any ```phone``` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking to filter your `List<C>` where any B has a `bobj` which has a `phone` containing 123, right?

```
IEnumerable<C> result = tobesearched.Where(t => t.b.bobj.Any(u => u.phone.Contains("123")));
```

..or with the class you posted in the comment below:

```
IEnumerable<Cdaily_snapshot> result = 
        tobesearched.Where(t => t.customer.phonenumbers.Any(u => u.phone.Contains("123")));
```

Comment: yes correct, but your solution didn't work. List<C> result = tobesearched.Where(t => t.b.bobj.Any(u => u.phone.Contains("123"))); it returns List of B not C

Comment: Here is my actual classes  `class Cdaily_snapshot{ public Customer customer;} class Customer{List<CphoneNumbers> phonenumbers;} class CphoneNumbers{public bool isDefault; public string phone;} ` Now in another class I have List<Cdaily_snapshot> cad; need to find all List<Cdaily_snapshot> from cad where phone is like 123 Sorry I dont know how to put it properly. Evertime I press enter, it is getting posted.

Comment: I edited my answer. This expression does indeed return an `IEnumerable<Cdaily_snapshot>`.

Comment: Sorry man it worked. Just added ToList<C>(). Thanks for help!